# In flex, how to pass data to handling function?

Tags: apache-flex, events, mouseevent

In flex, I am handling event like this,

myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redoOperation);

Now, I want to pass some value to redoOperation. (function redoOperation(myId:String)) How can I pass String to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an anonymous function and pass the parameter in that way. This is similar to how you would do it in JavaScript.

```
myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:Event):void { redoOperation(myId); });
```